# MongoDB: How to get the oldest Document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB collection that I have:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4c93478ac8f4f9d79151bd"),
    "property" : "prop_1",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T22:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4c93628ac8f4f9d79151be"),
    "property" : "prop_1",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-02T22:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4c93708ac8f4f9d79151c0"),
    "property" : "prop_2",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T22:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4c93738ac8f4f9d79151c1"),
    "property" : "prop_2",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-02T22:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I am in trouble with a query  to get the oldest document where attribute `property` equals to some specific value, for example, I need to find the oldest Document where attribute `property` is equal `prop_1`:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4c93478ac8f4f9d79151bd"),
    "property" : "prop_1",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T22:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Could you please provide any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter by `property`, [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) to get the oldest one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { property: "prop_1" } },
    { $sort: { created: -1 } }.
    { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LTkVtvdvod3)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) with `sort` and `limit` method,

```
db.collection.find({ property: "prop_1" })
.sort( { _id: -1 } ) // you can use { created: -1 }, but _id is always unique and made by timestamp
.limit(1);
```